# DIVs to keep moving down until the max height

Tags: html, css

```css
.parent {
  position:relative;
  background: azure;
  height: 200px;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class='parent'>
<h1 class='start'>START</h1>
<h2 class='in-between'>
  THIS TEXT IS SUPPOSED TO GET `OVERFLOW` WHEN `.FINISH` REACHES THE POINT OF LEAVING THE `.PARENT` FREESPACE FREESPACE FREESPACE FREESPACE FREESPACE FREESPACE
</h2>
<h1 class='finish'>FINISH</h1>
</div>
```

I want to make **.finish** stay inside **.parent** figure by making the **.in-between** to **overflow** with **scroll**.

Comment: What is max-height value. 100% means 100% of the text, so it will never overflow

Comment: @GerardoBLANCO the height of `.body` itself, Maybe i'm using it wrong, But I'm trying to set max height to the body only, Also the body isn't static to `250px` but i just used `250`.

Comment: I see the 250 for the body, but what do you want for the text?

Comment: @GerardoBLANCO if the `.text` is too long like the first one and `END` reached to the `END` of the `.body` to prevent it from getting out of it, And stay inside by making an `overflow`  on `.text` itself instead.

Comment: @DeadManWalking pay attention while editing please .. .there is no extra snippet, read the question carefully !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use flex layout like  this:

```css
.body {
  background-color: azure;
  border:1px solid;
  height: 250px;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
}
.text {
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class='body'>
  <h1>Hello</h1>
  <div class='text'>World World World World World World World World World World World World World World World World World World World World World World World World World World World World World World World World World World World World World World World World World World World World World World WorWorld ld World World World World World World World World World World World World World World World World World World World World World World World World World World World World World World World World World World World World World World World World World WorWorld ld World World World World World World World World World World World World</div>
  <h1>END</h1>
</div>
<div class='body'>
  <h1>Hello</h1>
  <div class='text'>World World World World World World World World World World World World World World World World d</div>
  <h1>END</h1>
</div>
<div class='body'>
  <h1>Hello</h1>
  <div class='text'>World </div>
  <h1>END</h1>
</div>
```